# Spring MVC application context path

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlets

My Spring MVC application is runnning on a Tomcat behind an Apache 2 acting as a proxy. I access my app directly in tomcat via an url like `http://localhost:8080/myapp`. I access my app via proxy with an url like `http://localhost/tomcat/myapp`.

The second url makes my app behave incorrectly, because it supposes it lives in `/myapp` context path, but via the proxy it should live in `/tomcat/myapp`.

Is there a variable in Spring or Servlet API, that holds `/tomcat/myapp` if I am accessing it via the proxy, and `/myapp` if I am accessing it directly?

Thanx

Comment: What do you mean by incorrectly?

Comment: I mean when I redirect to "/index.jsp" it actually redirects to "http://localhost/myapp/index.jsp" instead of "http://localhost/tomcat/myapp/index.jsp"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to enable proxy support then. This link might help you or give a little hint in this regards.

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

Comment: Why did somebody -1 this answer? It is correct, though the link should obviously point to http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html.

Comment: I found the solution on the page in the docs about proxy support. I shouldn't proxy from http://proxy/tc/ to http://tomcat:8080/. Instead I should proxy from http://proxy/myapp/ to http://tomcat:8080/myapp/

Comment: @artemb: I am so sorry to provide the wrong link. Actually, I copied few links at that time, and link to proxy page was the last one, and didn't get copied well. Therefore, I ended up pasting the wrong one. But the good thing is, you got it right. Thanks, I modified the post to include the correct link.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon this post while searching for the config setting for tomcat. 
There is a much easier way to configure tomcat to handle the exact situation you are experiencing. See:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/proxy-howto.html

Simple configure a connector for the proxy in tomcat, and the servlet/struts context path issues will resolve.

-edit: Obviously I didn't read #2 comment...

Answer (score -1):

> I mean when I redirect to "/index.jsp"
>   it actually redirects to
>   "http://localhost/myapp/index.jsp"
>   instead of
>   "http://localhost/tomcat/myapp/index.jsp"

Redirect to `index.jsp` instead of `/index.jsp`

When you redirect to /index.jsp this acts as an absolute url and it gets redirected to `myapp/index.jsp`. `index.jsp` is a relative url and will redirect to `tomcat/myapp/index.jsp`

Comment: What in case he intend to redirect from `tomcat/myapp/user/user.html` to `tomcat/myapp/index.html`

Comment: And FYI, `/index.html` is not absolute, its also relative but to the context.

Comment: Thanx, Adeel, that's exactly what I intend to. Spring MVC app is all about user-friendly urls like /user/add, in which case I think it is wrong to use redirects like "../../index.jsp"